# Very simple question regarding sum/difference identity

Tags: trigonometry, harmonic-analysis

If I have $\sin(0.7x-47t+C)$ where do I carry my constant $C$? The same with my sum-to-product identities.

This problem is showing up for me because I'm studying mechanical waves at the moment.

I thank you in advance.

Comment: I am not sure what the context of your question is. What do you mean by "carry my constant $C$"?

Comment: Like, suppose the function I wrote down is the function y(x,t) of a mechanical wave on a string. Now I want to add two of these functions. To do this I will use the sum-difference identity, but this constant "gets in the way" so to speak. So where do I put it on the formula? I can do the correct thing, but I want to know the exact reasoning behind just grouping it in.

Comment: You mention adding "two of these functions", that means you have another function other than $y(x, t) = \sin(0.7x - 47t + C)$. What is that function?
Anyway, if my extrapolation is not too far off, answers below might have helped you already.

Comment: Well yeah they've been helpful. Suppose the other function is y(x,t)=-sin(0.7x+47t+C). My main concern is why is it so valid to group C with whoever you want? I know this holds for just regular addition, but it seems weird to me to do this when these terms are inside a sine. Is there nothing weird?

Comment: It shouldn't be weird, $f(x)=\sin{(x)}$ is a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to[-1,1]$. It doesn't map $\mathbb{R}^2\to[-1,1]$, it just happens that this value in $\mathbb{R}$ has two variables and a constant involved.

Comment: I am not very sure what you mean by grouping. If you mean grouping so that you'll have only two terms adding/subtracting so that you can use the trigonometric identities, then the most general (but tedious) way is to decouple all terms. You will get an expression consisting of terms of the form $\sin(0.7x)\sin(47t)\sin(C)$ and all of its variants with $\sin$ replaced by $\cos$. It may not be immediately obvious that this final expression is unique. To prove this, you can consider one variable at a time and assume the other two are constants. (You might want to create another question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\sin{(A+C-B)}=\sin{(A)}\cos{(C-B)}+\cos{(A)}\sin{(C-B)}$

Can you use the angle difference identities for sine and cosine from here?

Comment: I've seen that I can produce the same answer indistinctly of whoever I group C with. But why does it work? Why doesn't it matter?

Comment: So the answer to those questions are the axioms of the real numbers. Mainly associativity and commutativity.